# Dynamically break UITableView into arbitrary sections?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, ios4

I have a core data application which displays a list of custom objects, each representing theatrical productions.

Each show object has a bunch of properties - name, logo, opening date, show type.

I can retrieve them fine, and sort by type just fine - but I would like each show type to be its own section in the table.

I don't know ahead of time how many show types will be represented in the result set, so I don't know initially what the numberofsections should be.

So I guess the question is - how would I go about dividing the result set into sections grouped by type?

Currently I'm doing this:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Show" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"type" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

// Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
// nil for section name key path means "no sections".
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];
aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write numberOfSections method so that it dynamically checks for the number of types. Then, whenever a new type rolls in, just do a [tableView reloadData];

Comment: Whoops, this was a pretty simple fix, I just needed to add:

    - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Display the authors' names as section headings.
    return [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] name];
}

And change this bit:

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"type" cacheName:@"Root"];